# .bash_profile: bad assignment

Tags: bash, macos

I'm setting up the environment for React native on my Mac, and I have to had these environment variables:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

So my `.bash_profile` file looks like this (see below); I'm afraid the definition of the `PATH` variable of my different setup get in conflict.

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.6
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# added by Anaconda3 4.3.0 installer
export PATH="//anaconda/bin:$PATH"

# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for Flutter
export PATH = /Users/juliencorbin/flutter/bin:$PATH

# Setting path for Android home (react native tools) 
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools


export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

Furthermore, when I run `source $HOME/.bash_profile`, I get the following error:

```
/Users/myname/.bash_profile:16: bad assignment
```

How am I supposed to deal with all those PATH assignment ? specially for React native which is the one I want to work with the most right now.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The error is in this line:

```
export PATH = /Users/juliencorbin/flutter/bin:$PATH
```

Bash [splits each command line in words](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html#Word-Splitting) using the characters listed in the `IFS` environment variable as delimiters (the default delimiters are `<space>`, `<tab>` and `<newline>`). The first word is the command to execute, the rest of them are its arguments.

The line above is split in 4 words. The first word is `export` and it receives 3 arguments (`PATH`, `=` and `/Users/juliencorbin/flutter/bin:...`) while it expects only one.

The assignments in Bash commands and scripts **must not** have white space characters around the `=` operator. The errant line must be:

```
export PATH=/Users/juliencorbin/flutter/bin:$PATH
```

Remove the spaces from around `=` and make sure there are no spaces embedded in the value you want to assign to `PATH`. Wrap the entire right-hand side value in quotes (`"/Users/... "`) if one of the paths you put there contain spaces.

Comment: I didn't know that, very interesting and thank you very much for your help @axiac ! Hence I have a question: will my PATH variable be the right one for each of these stuff (Anaconda, Python, flutter, etc.) ? when I print `echo $PATH` I feel like I get an addition of all those paths: (see comment below)

Comment: `/Users/juliencorbin/.nvm/versions/node/v8.0.0/bin:/Users/juliencorbin/flutter/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin://anaconda/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin://anaconda/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/local/opt/node@8/bin:/Users/juliencorbin/.yarn/bin:./bin:./node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/opt/rbenv/shims:/usr/local/opt/rbenv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/sbin` etc. plus the Android path (too long to paste everything)

Comment: When you type in a terminal a command name without a path (f.e. `ls`), the shell searches each path listed in `$PATH` until it finds the command. It seems your `.bash_profile` is executed twice (or, somehow, some paths are added twice to the `PATH` variable). This is not a problem *per se*.

Comment: Allright. so that is perfect. exactly what I was looking for. thank you very much @axiac !